# Usage of entropy function

Tags: matlab, statistics, entropy

I was trying to find the entropy of a certain probability distribution in MATLAB. For p, I tried doing

```
E = -sum(p .* log2(p))
```

and `Echeck = entropy(p)`

Shouldn't E and Echeck be same?

The matlab help on entropy does say Entropy is defined as -sum(p.*log2(p))
where p contains the histogram counts returned from imhist.But also that entropy converts any class other than logical to uint8 for the histogram count calculation since it is actually trying to calculate the entropy of a grayscale image and hence wants the pixel values to be discrete.
So I guess it's incorrect to use this function for my purpose?
Is there a good alternative?

Comment: What is your variable `p`? The expression `sum(p .* log2(p))` will return a scalar if `p` is a vector, whereas the function `entropy` expects to operate on a matrix representing a grayscale image. In effect, the `entropy` function is defined by `entropy(I) = -sum(imhist(I) .* log2(imhist(I)))`.

Comment: @Chris Taylor, You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: p is a probability distribution - a NX1 vector of probability values in my case.

Comment: @Oli meh, yours was more complete (also, I don't have the image processing toolbox so I can't see the source of `entropy`, which I think added to your answer)

Comment: The MATLAB entropy function also returned a scalar for vector p. The difference in values is probably due to turning double probability values in the vector p to uint8. I was wondering if MATLAB had a more straightforward way to calculate entropy from of any probability distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `open entropy` to check the code, and there is a line:

```
if ~islogical(I)
  I = im2uint8(I);
end
p = imhist(I(:));
```

which mean that the input is converted to uint8, and then the function computes **the entropy of the histogram of the input**, and not of the input itself.

That explains the difference.